# PyQt - Transparent background

Tags: background, pyqt, transparent

I try to make the background of my window transparent. But under widgets which are on it i see parts of my desktop-image.
Now i have this in constructor:

> ```
>     self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
>     self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_QuitOnClose,True)
>
>     self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)
>     self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to gs's answer, this faq explains why (before Qt 4.5) you cannot achieve this:

[FAQ Link:](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/faqs/faq.2007-02-08.3940505976)

> There is no direct support for partial
>   transparency, where the window is
>   transparent and the widgets on it are
>   not in Qt.

Remember, PyQt's most recent version was created against Qt 4.4, and so does not support the semi-transparent window you desire. gs's other answer, about setAutoFillBackground(True) would work if you were setting the background colour of your main window to anything other than transparent.

Also, see the documentation for Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, it says you can't depend on the transparent effect that you have so far had:

[Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

> Indicates that the widget has no
>   background, i.e. when the widget
>   receives paint events, the background
>   is not automatically repainted. Note:
>   Unlike WA_OpaquePaintEvent, newly
>   exposed areas are never filled with
>   the background (e.g after showing a
>   window for the first time the user can
>   see "through" it until the application
>   processes the paint events). This is
>   set/cleared by the widget's author.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#creating-translucent-windows):

> ### Creating Translucent Windows
>
> Since Qt 4.5, it has been possible to
>   create windows with translucent
>   regions on window systems that support
>   compositing.
>
> To enable this feature in a top-level
>   widget, set its
>   Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground attribute
>   with setAttribute() and ensure that
>   its background is painted with
>   non-opaque colors in the regions you
>   want to be partially transparent.

PyQt is still Qt 4.4, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: There isn't Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground attribute in PyQt =(. Any ideas?

Comment: +1: That is what gs is saying. You can't do it because PyQt was created against Qt 4.4, and so the semi-transparent features you're looking for aren't available yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your widgets:

```
widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

I think you could also set it in the Qt Designer.

Comment: I've also tried to draw transparent png-image... It doesn't work too =(.

Comment: It would work if you were doing anything else other than a transparent background on your main window and opaque on your child widget.